# setWifiEnabled is deprecated , How to turn on wifi?

Tags: android-wifi

i have a switch which i made to open and close the wifi
but its is not working .
this is my code

and the wifiManager.setWifiEnabled() showing as deprecated .

```
 wlanswitch.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new CompoundButton.OnCheckedChangeListener() {
            @Override
            public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton compoundButton, boolean isChecked) {

                if(isChecked){

                    wifiManager.setWifiEnabled(false);
                    wlanswitch.setText("ON");
                }else{
                    wifiManager.setWifiEnabled(false);
                    wlanswitch.setText("OFF");
                }
            }
        });
        if(wifiManager.isWifiEnabled()){
            wlanswitch.setChecked(true);
            wlanswitch.setText("ON");
        }else{
            wlanswitch.setChecked(false);
            wlanswitch.setText("OFF");
        }
```

Comment: Starting with API level 29 (Android 10) it's not possible to programmatically toggle WiFi.

Comment: so how to open wifi on button click

Comment: You can't do it over Android 10.